# SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT Not Timing Out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, timeout, odbc

**Setup**

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have an ODBC call to a stored procedure that should time out after 3 seconds by using the SQLSetStmtAttr function with the SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT parameter.

```
SQLSetStmtAttr( command, SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)&timeOut, NULL );
```

**Test**

I set a delay in the stored procedure for 15 seconds.  The stored proc does indeed take just over 15 seconds to return.

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15'
```

**Issue**

The problem is that the stored procedure returns correctly, where I am expecting an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue discovered.

The timeOut variable (int) was passed into SQLSetStmtAttr as a reference, and the value of the reference location was much larger than 3.

Correct implementation is:

```
SQLSetStmtAttr( command, SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)timeOut, NULL );
```